# Why orbit-db data didn't save on global network

Tags: javascript, node.js, p2p, ipfs, orbitdb

I am trying use orbit-db for share data in p2p network

but i don't why i can't get data in local pc

code 1 run in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dew-vqekz

code 2 run in local pc

> same as code 1 , but remove this line

```
hash = await db.put("world", { updated: 7777777 }, { pin: true });
```

i have checked `dbAddress` is same = `/orbitdb/zdpuAwasWRQmp6B937QDsm8V9oM3a2N8VAGkGVNctBsGTxgan/hello`

but i can't see `{ updated: 7777777 }` when run code 2 at local pc